# How to find the total views of all videos in a YouTube PlayList?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I am trying to find the total number of views of all videos in a playlist I own in YouTube. I can see that a "total views" number is posted under the playlist name. However this appears to be the number of views generated by entering the playlist first. When I add up the number of views of individual videos I get a substantially larger number because, I assume, most of videos are watched by following a link other than the playlist.

In particular using the following JS in the YT console

```
ytInitialData.header.playlistHeaderRenderer.viewCountText.simpleText
```

just gives the same number that is available under the playlist name.

ChatGPT gives the following JS

```
var totalViews = 0;
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('ytd-playlist-video-renderer');
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
  var viewsElement = videos[i].querySelector('#metadata > span:nth- child(1)');
  if (viewsElement !== null) {
     var views = viewsElement.textContent.trim().replace(/\D/g,'');
     totalViews += parseInt(views);
  }
 }
 console.log('Total views of all videos in the playlist: ' + totalViews);
```

But this gives a total count of 0.

Edit:

[A solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75992593/how-to-find-total-views-in-a-youtube-playlist).

Comment: As you stated, adding the individual views for each video in a playlist will equal the combined total for all videos in the playlist.  If you are looking for a coded solution that is unfortunately [off-topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for Web Applications.   You could look at the HTML after clicking on a "View full playlist" link and parse out the video titles and view counts based on the tag names, but again that is off-topic. Maybe try [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or reformat your question to fit this site.

Comment: @BlindSpots Did you mean that adding the individual views will NOT equal the  given playlist view number?

Comment: Yes, you indicated that you are not interested in total Playlist views but rather total views of all videos that are in a particular playlist.  I pointed out the info is displayed for scraping.

Comment: I'll link to a solution later tonight.